# JDialog not showing minimize/close button

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jdialog

When researching the problem, it seems most people are wanting to do the opposite (i.e remove the minimize/close button).
I've had no success using the reoccurrent `setUndecorated` and `setDefaultCloseOperation`

Here is my code:

```
private class TestDialog extends JDialog 
{
    public static final String title_ = "Test Dialog";

    public TestDialog(JFrame parent)
    {
        super(parent,title_,true);
        setMinimumSize(new Dimension(500,500));
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setUndecorated(false);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

When I display the dialog I get the following:

[image]

**Other info:**
OS: Ubuntu
Java version: 1.7.0_55

Comment: Do you want to remove the close/minimize buttons? Why don't you inherit from JWindow rather than JDialog?

Comment: I want the close/minimize buttons to appear. I think a JWindow would be ill-suited considering it doesn't embed a title bar.

Comment: Use JFrame instead of JDialog

Comment: For my context, a JDialog is much better suited. Mainly for modaility

Answer (score 3):

It's not clear where things may have gone awry, but the complete example below works on Ubuntu 12, Java 6; it may help you pin down the problem. Note that *all* [top-level container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html)s must be constructed on the [event dispatch thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).

[image]

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;


public class TestDialog extends JDialog {

    public static final String title = "Test Dialog";

    public TestDialog(JFrame parent) {
        super(parent, title, true);
        add(new JPanel(){

            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(320, 240);
            }
        });
        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new TestDialog(null).setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response @trashgod. Having tried your exact example, I still don't get the close button you seem to get. I installed an earlier version of the jdk (1.6.0) and still nothing. The only thing I can think of now is an issue with Ubuntu 14.04 and/or GNOME.

Comment: @Harry: Looks the same on Ubuntu 14 with Java 7.

Comment: OK. It seems to be an issue with the GNOME shell. When I switch to Unity (default in Ubuntu), it works. Thanks for the help @trashgod

Comment: @Harry: Did you end up finding a solution to this problem which did not involve moving to Unity? I am having the same problem at the moment.

Comment: @Fooble: Afraid not. Right clicking the dialog title area and selecting close is the only solution I found....

Answer (score 1):

I have found a temporary solution of sorts, if you change the following line:

```
super(parent, title, true);
```

to

```
super(null, title, Dialog.ModalityType.MODELESS);
```

then the window close button will appear when using GNOME. I am not sure what other issues this could cause however.

Comment: I'm surprised that compiles. I get an "ambiguous constructor" error as there are multiple constructors which match that signature. I found a way around this however: `super(null, title, Dialog.ModalityType.MODELESS);`

Comment: My bad, I actually used Dialog.ModalityType.MODELESS myself. I copied the code from your original example and forgot to change the last parameter.