# Why must parent=null for Dialog.ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL to work?

Tags: java, linux, modal-dialog, jdialog

I was encountering a Linux specific issue related to JDialog and missing X (close) icon and it being modal.

The workaround per [JDialog not showing minimize/close button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26162178/jdialog-not-showing-minimize-close-button)  is to use the following :

```
super(null, title, Dialog.ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);
```

instead of using

```
super(parent, title, true);
```

This actually works. 
The next step was to try it with a parent reference :

```
super(parent, title, Dialog.ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);
```

This no longer worked as the JDialog no longer was modal. 
Attempting to utilize the setModal(true); call in any fashion wouldn't work either.

Reviewing the actual JDialog constructor code it traverses into the Dialog constructor code which in turn calls setModalityType(...);
The Dialog constructor executes an IF condition using the Parent variable which only validates the parameter and returns an exception if there was an issue.

Reviewing the setModalityType(..) call which the Dialog constructor calls, I didn't see any code doing things differently if a parent existed.

This leads me to the following 2 questions. 
1 - What is it that changes the Dialog.ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL behavior whether a parent is passed in or not?
2 - What are the repercussions of not passing in a parent. Preliminary testing isn't showing any difference in behavior by passing in null as a parent.

In case it matters, the JDK version : 1.8